# Why does mysql evaluate (TRUE or TRUE and FALSE) to true?

Tags: mysql, sql

If you type

```
SELECT (true or true and false)
```

in mysql it will return `1` which is `true`. Why is that so? What's the order of evaluation in boolean expressions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the MySQL documentation on operator precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html), AND is evaluated before OR.
That means your expression `(true OR true AND false)` is evaluated as `(true OR (true AND false))`.